# warning 'newdata' had X row but variables found have Y rows

Tags: regression, logistic-regression, accuracy, confusion-matrix, linear-models

## Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA)+logistic regression model

lda_model <- lda(train_labels ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = train_data)

## LDA scores for the training data using the predict function

lda_scores_train <- predict(lda_model, train_data)$x

## Train logistic regression model

logistic_model <- glm(train_labels_binary ~ lda_scores_train[, 1] + lda_scores_train[, 2], family = binomial)

## Predict probabilities for the test data

lda_scores_test <- predict(lda_model, test_data)$x

predicted_probabilities <- predict(logistic_model, newdata = data.frame(lda_scores_test), type = "response")

## Convert probabilities to binary predictions

predicted_labels <- ifelse(predicted_probabilities > 0.5, 1, 0)

> predicted_probabilities <- predict(logistic_model, newdata = data.frame(lda_scores_test), type = "response")
> Warning message:
> 'newdata' had 45 rows but variables found have 105 rows

It is giving me the error. So I am unable to calculate the confusion matrix. I am trying to evaluate LDA+Logistic regression model

Comment: It is giving me the error. So I am unable to calculate the confusion matrix. I am trying to evaluate LDA+Logistic regression model